# Brightness of LEDs

Tags: led, lighting, brightness

I am currently in the design phase of building a digital clock (about 2ft by 4ft in size.) It should be fairly visible from a considerable distance (about 100 ft) and visible during the day.

I am using through hole LEDs for the segments of the digits.

My problem is I am not able to gauge the brightness of the LEDs from the datasheets. I think my problem is I do not have a visual reference point when doing comparisons.

Will be happy if the community can assist with some pointers to videos or articles with lots of visuals describing LED brightness.

Comment: why are you not doing the research on the internet yourself?

Comment: Basically a shopping question and off topic.

Comment: Shopping? Nope. OP wants to make a panel out of LEDs they source themselves, and they're looking for selection criteria.

Comment: Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Photometry has everything you need to calculate what you need. We can't give you free classroom training on photometrics here, please ask concise questions.

Comment: Traffic lights in Turkey contain around 100 pcs of 10mm clear LEDs and they dissipate around 10 Watts. They are visible from at least 50 meters. This can be a reference to you.

Comment: I think this is a valid question. @Ariser, you might as well just link to "The Art of Electronics" textbook for every question and say "everything you need to calculate that is in here". He want's to know how to estimate visibility using the datasheet, simple as that.

Comment: @Drew: The question is valid, but doesn't show any prior research.

Comment: Probably the easiest way is to just buy a few and experiment with them in various configurations. If you don't buy from a proper distributor it's likely the performance numbers will be well on the optimistic side. You're going to need a filter in front, and there are a range of possibilities there.

Comment: @Rohat Kılıç: Traffic lights are meant only to be seen in a distinct angular direction. They use a tubular ambient light filter. This is much different from a clock display.

Answer (score 1):

LEDs are rated in *lumens* for total light and *candelas* for brightness in a given direction. More here: https://www.diodedynamics.com/info/research/led/led-brightness.html

An LED specification will also have a dispersion pattern, that is, how it is focused. This is somewhat analogous to viewing angle.

And now, a hacktastical solution.

There are commercial LED display panels that use smaller modules which can be combined to make displays of arbitrary size. They're driven with a video signal via a controller, so the display can be anything you like.

An example product (not a recommendation, only for illustrative purposes):

https://display-innovations.com/displays/digital-led-screens-modular

There are many vendors in this LED-based ‘digital signage’ space (many in China and Taiwan), so it's likely that you could find a low-priced source on Alibaba or suchlike.

Not as fun as making your own bespoke panel, yes, but it probably is more cost-effective (especially if you're making just one) and more aesthetically pleasing since the display can use any font and background.

As a bonus, you could potentially sell advertising on your clock and help defray the cost of building it.

Answer (score 1):

> about 100 ft and visible during the day […] through hole LEDs

Forget it. The problem is your through-hole LEDs, but many SMD types as well employ a tiny reflector.

That reflector isn't just reflecting the light from the LED chip. It also reflects sunlight. Even on a dim day, sunlight is about 100,000 times brighter than the brightest LEDs. Your clock will only ever show 88:88.

You need either reflectorless SMD LEDs —and plenty of those, because without a reflector, they are pretty dark—, or a translucent screen plus backlight.